# How to create a custom transformer with out any input column?

Tags: mleap

We have requirement where in we wanted to generate scores of our model with some random values in between 0-1.

To do that we wanted to have a custom transformer which will be generating random numbers with out any input fields.

So can we generate a transformer without input fields in mleap?

Like usually we do create as below:

```
import ml.combust.mleap.core.Model
import ml.combust.mleap.core.types._

case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model {
  private val rnd = scala.util.Random

  def apply(): Double = rnd.nextFloat

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType("input" -> ScalarType.String).get

  override def outputSchema: StructType = StructType("output" -> ScalarType.Double ).get

}
```

How to make it as input schema no necessary to put?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried that, but given how I achieved to have a custom transformer with multiple input fields ...

```
package org.apache.spark.ml.feature.mleap

import ml.combust.mleap.core.Model
import ml.combust.mleap.core.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._

case class PropertyGroupAggregatorBaseModel (props: Array[String],
                                        aggFunc: String) extends Model {
  val outputSize = props.size

  //having multiple inputs, you will have apply with a parameter Seq[Any]
  def apply(features: Seq[Any]): Vector = {
    val properties = features(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]
    val values = features(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
    val mapping = properties.zip(values)
    val histogram = props.foldLeft(Array.empty[Double]){
      (acc, property) =>
        val newValues = mapping.filter(x => x._1 == property).map(x => x._2)
        val newAggregate = aggFunc match {
          case "sum" => newValues.sum.toDouble
          case "count" => newValues.size.toDouble
          case "avg" => (newValues.sum / Math.max(newValues.size, 1)).toDouble
        }
        acc :+ newAggregate
    }

    Vectors.dense(histogram)
  }

  override def inputSchema: StructType =  {
    //here you define the input 
    val inputFields = Seq(
      StructField("input1" -> ListType(BasicType.String)),
      StructField("input2" -> ListType(BasicType.Double))
    )
    StructType(inputFields).get
  }

  override def outputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("output" -> TensorType.Double(outputSize))).get
}
```

My suggestion would be, that the apply might already work for you. I guess if you define `inputSchema` as follows, it might work:

```
override def inputSchema: StructType =  {
    //here you define the input 
    val inputFields = Seq.empty[StructField]
    StructType(inputFields).get
  }
```